# Redirecting request on Route53 domain to cloudflare domain

Tags: cloudflare, amazon-route53

I have a domain managed by route `53`. Say `www.domain.com`. I have another domain managed by `cloudfront`. Say `example.com`.

When the user is requesting a specific file on domain.com, I want the file to be served by cloudflare domain.

For example,

`http://www.domain.com/new.jpg` should be redirected to `www.example.com/new.jpg`.

I am not sure how to do this in Route53 and cloudflare.

Any suggestions?

-Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content to be "served from" example.com, then just do a CNAME mapping on your Route53. CNAME record www.domain.com to www.example.com.
In addition to the above mapping on your DNS, you also need to tell the hosting provider (I guess cloudflare for you) to allow serving on this domain as well. [How do I do CNAME setup? – CloudFlare Support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-).

However, when you try this in a browser, the URL will still remain as domain.com (though the content will come from example.com). If you need to URL too be changed, then you need a re-directing service - This should be an HTTP 301 redirect (and not at DNS/Route53), this requires running a web-server. If your domain.com was registered at GoDaddy, they have a redirect service which helps do this (basically you park the domain there itself, without moving to Route53 and tell them to "domain forward" to example.com)

Comment: I tried this Sony, and was given error repeatedly by cloudflare. I also thought this would be the way to do it.

Comment: You have an additional setup required on the hosting provider. I have edited the answer above.